# simple formula for a finite sum of multinomial numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

Let $k,m$ and $r$ be positive integers.

Define 
$$\Omega(k,m,r) = \binom k {m-2r}\binom {k-m+2r} r$$
and
$$\Omega(k,m) = \sum_{r=\max\{0,m-k\}}^{[\frac{m}{2}]}\Omega(k,m,r).$$

> **Question.**
>    1. Is $\Omega(k,m)$ has a simple formula? 
>    2. Is $\frac{\sum_{r=\max\{0,m-k\}}^{[\frac{m}{2}]}r\Omega(k,m,r)}{(k+m)\Omega(k,m)}$ has a simple formula?

**Background:**
If we want to calculate the numbers of $m$ white balls insert in $k-1$ black balls with the constraint that continuum three white balls $\circ\circ\circ$ is forbidden, then we can derive the formula above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that
$$\Omega(k,m,r) = \binom{k}{m-2r,r,k-m+r}.$$
It follows that $\Omega(k,m)$ equals the coefficient of $x^{m-k}$ in $(1+x+x^{-1})^k$, which is the same as the coefficient of $x^{m}$ in $(1+x+x^2)^k$, also known as the [trinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_triangle) $\binom{k}{m-k}_2$. That is, $\Omega(k,m) = \binom{k}{m-k}_2$.

The sum $\sum_r r\Omega(k,m,r)$ can be obtained by differentiating $(1+xy+x^{-1})^k$ at $y=1$, which yields $k\binom{k-1}{m-k-1}_2$.

Comment: If we let $m=\rho k$,$k$ goes to infinity, can we obtain the limit  $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\Omega(k+1,m)/\Omega(k,m)$?

Comment: @YuhuanLei: Check out this paper: [Asymptotic Estimate for the Multinomial Coefficients](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL23/Li/li14.html).

Comment: thank you very much! The result in that paper considers the case that $q>3$ and $c$ is a positive integer. Is there any result about the case that $q=3$ and $c\in[-1,1]$?

Comment: I have asked Jiyou Li，he said the case I concerned is also valid.